# Windows installer, check existence of package

Tags: windows, windows-installer

Using windows, I can uninstall software via script/command line as follows:

```
msiexec /x {00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}
```

Is there a method to just test for the existence of the given package, without affecting it?

I'm interested in a true/false or any other input, indicating whether the package exists on the machine, and can be removed using Windows installer with the given command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use REGEDIT command and check, if the key with name corresponding to the product code of package is present under the following key

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall
```

If it is not there, it can also be here:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\
```

Following BATCH command can do it for you, only replace the product code with real one:

```
@echo off
SET PRODUCTKEY=HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall
REM *** Write your package code here
REG QUERY %PRODUCTKEY%\{00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}
IF NOT %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 0 (GOTO :INSTALL) ELSE GOTO :ENDHERE  
:INSTALL
ECHO Not installed
GOTO :END 
:ENDHERE
ECHO Installed
GOTO :END
:END
```

Or the one-line version:

```
REG QUERY HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}
```

Alternatively you can run

```
msiexec.exe /fp {00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}
```

which repairs a package only if a file is missing, so it should do nothing to correctly installed packages. But the installer would be launched and would try to repair the installed package.